# Datatables.js with java servlet and per row submit button

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets, datatables

I am creating a page where I'm using DataTables.js to display information and the plan is to have a submit button on each row that submits a form with the row information.

At first I used a jstl  loop to generate the table which worked but this ran into some issue with having a  tag in the loop of the table to submit each row.

So now, in the servlet, I have a List that is passed from the controller and to the servlet and is the converted to a Json string using Gson. In the console, when navigating to the page, I can confirm that the the string has the correct data since I printed it out in the console.

Now my question is how do I utilize this attribute, that I do set using req.setAttribute("allX", allX) to pass it to the JSP.

I have a script tag at the bottom of the JSP to populate the table which is

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var allx = ${allX}

    $('#allTable').DataTable({
        "data" : allx

    });
});
</script>
```

Above in the jsp I have a  tag with the id allTable.

What I really need help with is correctly displaying the data in the table from the Json string and then adding a submit button to each row that submits the information in the row back to the servlet, which at this point and will probably only ever be one data point per row. I'm okay with handling the data in the servlet and processing it for use elsewhere, its just this table data, I having a huge issue with.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if I understood your question correctly, but I assume you have no issue in collecting the data and composing the response to the client, but having issues with displaying the data in the datatables on the client side.

You would want to send an array of objects, so datatables can display it properly. Each element in that array would be an object, describing a complete row. Here is an example:

```js
// You can use array of objects. Each object will be a row in the table.
// Compose it on the server or client side and give to DataTables for processing.
// Your objects can have many keys. You can tell DataTables which to use. In this
// example, I use allX.id and allX.type, while ignoring allX.color.
var allX = [
  { id: '0', type: 'pencil', color: 'blue' },
  { id: '1', type: 'pen', color: 'orange' },
  { id: '2', type: 'marker', color: 'black' }
];

var table = $('#allTable').DataTable({

  data: allX, // allX here is our array, which contains the data to display in the table

  columns: [{
      data: 'id',        // object key to look for value
      title: 'ID'        // give a title to your column
    },
    {
      data: 'type',      // our second column description
      title: 'Type'
    },
    {
      width: '30%',      // our buttons column
      orderable: false   // we will describe it further in 'columnDefs'
    },
  ],

  "columnDefs": [{
    "targets": -1,       // -1 = last column
    "data": null,        // no data for this column, instead we will show default content, described in 'defaultContent'
    "defaultContent": "<button id='submit-btn'>Submit</button> <button id='delete-btn'>Delete</button>"
  }],

});

// catch a button click event
$('#allTable').on('click', 'button', function() {
  // create an object from a row data
  var rowData = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
  // fire a function, based on the button id that was clicked
  if (this.id === 'submit-btn') {
    submitData(rowData);
  } else if (this.id === 'delete-btn') {
    deleteData(rowData);
  }
});


function submitData(data) {
  // Process your row data and submit here.
  // e.g. data === { id: '1', type: 'pen', color: 'orange' }
  // Even though your table shows only selected columns, the row data
  // will still contain the complete object.
  // I would recommend against sending a complete object. In your case,
  // with a single data point, perhaps it is fine though. However,
  // always send bare minimum. For example, if you want to delete an
  // entry on the server side, just send the id of the entry and let
  // the server locate it and delete it by id. It doesn't need all other
  // fields.
}

function deleteData(data) {
  // Just an example how you can have various buttons on each row.
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked! I really appreciate it.